# Doing Backup DB from Stored Procedure works in local but no in production

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

i need to backup my database by a clic button on a web app. I put the code in a SP which is called by the clic, it create a .bak and store it in a server folder.
This works perfectly executing the SP directly in SQL SERVER, clicking the button in local web app, but no in production.

The code in local and production are the same.

I tried to do the BK in many ways:

- backup database DATABASENAME to disk = @route
- set @query = 'backup database DATABASENAME to disk = ' + '''' + @route + ''''
  exec(@query)
  Catching the info in a variable.
- set @query = 'backup database DATABASENAME to disk = ' + '''' + @route + ''''
  exec @respuesta = sp_executesql @query

Again, all of these ways works in local but no in production.

Here is my SP:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_IWBackupDatabase]
as
begin
declare @route nvarchar(500), @query nvarchar(1000), @respuesta int = 1
set nocount on
set @route = 'I:\SERVERFOLVER\BackupDB\DATABASENAMEFull.bak'

begin try
backup database DATABASENAME to disk = @route
set @respuesta = 0
end try
begin catch
set @respuesta = 1
end catch

select @respuesta Respuesta
end
```

Here is my call in with JS:

```
function BackupDatabase() {
    $.post('main.php', {
        action: 'BackupDatabase'
    }, function(e) {
        if (e.error) {
            if (e.r == "SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.") {
                Core.ShowNotific8('It WORKS', 'lime', false);
                DBWasBackUp = 1;
                $('#btn_CreateDBBK').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                Core.ShowNotific8('It NOT WORKS', 'ruby', false);
                DBWasBackUp = 0;
                $('#btn_CreateDBBK').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        } else {
            if (e.r[0]['Respuesta'] == '0') {
                Core.ShowNotific8('It WORKS', 'lime', false);
                DBWasBackUp = 1;
                $('#btn_CreateDBBK').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                Core.ShowNotific8('It NOT WORKS', 'ruby', false);
                DBWasBackUp = 0;
                $('#btn_CreateDBBK').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        }

    });
    return false;
}
```

Finally, here is the call from PHP:

```
function BackupDatabase()
{
$cnx = $this->connectSqlSrv():
$sth = $cnx->prepare("Exec sp_IWBackupDatabase");
$retval json_encode($retval);
}
```

Comment: Is the production web app running in IIS?

Comment: You have the path where to save the backup hardcoded in the stored procedure. Are you sure you have access and write permissions on it from the prod server?

Comment: `$retval json_encode($retval);` should be `echo json_encode($retval);`.  Not related to your problem tho.  Is the folder you're putting these files in writable?  Can the web user write to that folder?

Comment: @JakeSteffen Yes, and the folder were i pretend to store the SP was configured like  Virtual Directory.

Comment: @prieber My bad, i wrote bad the function here but its ok in the web code. Yes, the folder is writable and the user have permissions over the folder.

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez Yes, im using that folder to store pictures from another app, and removing that pictures from the web that im trying to do the .bak.

Comment: @JesusBautista the permissions of the user who is using the page have nothing to do in this case. You are running the SP on a database, the user that you are using to connect to the database from the connection string, has access to that path? plus i don t think you have the db on the same server with the IIS for the page

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez Ok, im not exactly sure what you mean with: "the db user has to have access to the path", but i can do the .bak in SQL executing the SP using these credentials. The DB and the IIS are in the same server, for the built in local im using the public ip to connect.

Comment: @JesusBautista The Sql server agent runs under a specific account. That account should have access to that path.
Imagine you connect to the your database with the user stackoverflow and password test.
The user stackoverflow should have access to that path and write privileges.

You can also find the login account for the Sql Server Agent by using the sql Server Configuation Manager and clicking on the Sql Server Services node.

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez Oh, ok. I put the administrator as login to SQL Server Agent, even for SQL Server (just to try) and restarted the services. I still can't do the .bak

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez With fear of being redundant I should clarify that in local, the .bak stores in the server folder without problem. Its weird.

Comment: @JesusBautista if storing it in local it works then I am 100% sure is a problem with permissions. One last thing I can suggest is to have a look at : https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/224071/troubleshooting-sql-server-backup-and-restore-operations    scenario 3 is about permissions. Also I see you are catching the error of the stored procedure. If you can do a temp table and store the errors generated https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-message-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . I have no other ideas on what you can do

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez I have my doubts about permissions, the only user i use is administrator and sa, so they have full access. The SP doesn't generate any errors. I'll check the links anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @JesusBautista I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433567/php-pdofetch-assoc-doesnt-detect-select-after-backup-in-stored-procedure/56438860#56438860) will help you to find a solution. Try to use an output parameter in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely permissions. When you are running the site under VS the user is running as your local windows user. When you deploy to IIS it is running as the application pool user. Check what user this is running under by going to IIS > Sites > Right Click The Site > Manage WebSite > Advanced Settings. That is the user it is running as and that user may need to have SQL access. If you need to add a new application pool look here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/#how-to

Comment: What did you determine from this? @Jesus Bautista

Comment: I checked all you suggest me. Everything seems to be ok. The site is using the admin credentials, and its linked to an application pool.