# My .bak file gone when I write backup code in stored procedure using SQL Server and call it via PHP laravel api

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I wrote backup code using Microsoft SQL Server in stored procedure and it did work when I Execute the Stored procedure directly using batch file. But, when I try to calling it from PHP Laravel api, there's no file .bak produced. (I check the folder and file .bak appear and gone in a second, it's success but file is gone)

Here's The Stored Procedure Code

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_CM_BATCH_DAILY]    Script Date: 26/07/2022 11:49:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE NAME : SP_CM_BATCH_DAILY
CREATED DATE   : 2022-07-01
CREATED USER   : 
REMARK         : 
EXAMPLE        : 

EXEC SP_CM_BATCH_DAILY @iFlag = 'BATCH_TEST'
---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CM_BATCH_DAILY]
      @iFlag                    VARCHAR (50)
    , @p_dbnameFull             VARCHAR (20)    =   NULL
    , @p_statusBackup           CHAR(1)         =   NULL
AS
BEGIN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET NOCOUNT ON
     IF @iFlag = 'BACKUP_FULL'              BEGIN GOTO BACKUP_FULL;                     END
ELSE IF @iFlag = 'BACKUP_HISTORY'           BEGIN GOTO BACKUP_HISTORY;              END
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BACKUP_FULL:
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(256) -- database name  
    DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(512) -- path for backup files  
    DECLARE @fileName NVARCHAR(512) -- filename for backup  
    DECLARE @fileDate NVARCHAR(40) -- used for file name
 
    -- specify database backup directory
    SET @path = 'D:\FullBackup\'
 
    -- specify filename format
    SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 
 
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR  
    SELECT name 
    FROM master.sys.databases 
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  -- exclude these databases
    AND state = 0 -- database is online
    AND is_in_standby = 0 -- database is not read only for log shipping
 
    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
       SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'  
       BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName  
 
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
    END   
 
    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
END
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BACKUP_HISTORY:
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN  TRANSACTION SP_DM_BATCH_DAILY__BATCH_TEST
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO CM_BATCH_HIST (batch_id, batch_date, batch_rst, log_ip, remarks)
            SELECT @p_dbnameFull
                 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), convert(VARCHAR, GETDATE()) , 120)
                 , @p_statusBackup
                 , '127.0.0.1'
                 , NULL;
        END
        COMMIT TRANSACTION SP_DM_BATCH_DAILY__BATCH_TEST

        SELECT 'Y' AS RTN_CODE;

        IF ( @@ERROR <> 0 ) BEGIN
            SELECT @@ERROR, ERROR_MESSAGE();
        END 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SP_DM_BATCH_DAILY__BATCH_TEST
        GOTO ERROR;
    END CATCH
    SELECT 'Y' AS RTN_CODE;
    RETURN;  
END
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR:
BEGIN
    SELECT @iFlag AS ERR_FLAG, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERR_MSG, 'E' AS RTN_CODE
    RETURN;
END
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END
```

It's in api.php

```
Route::get('/backupDevHubdb',[ColorController::class,'backupDevHubdb']);
```

the function that called from api.php

```
public function backupDevHubdb(){
        try{
            $responseDB = DB::statement("EXEC [SP_CM_BATCH_DAILY] @iFlag = 'BACKUP_FULL'");
            return response("BACKUP COMPLETED ".$responseDB);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            return response($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and it's the .bat file to call that php.api via curl

```
@echo off

curl -X GET "http://localhost:8000/api/backupDevHubdb" 

exit
```

Comment: You've got a semblance of error handling in the `backup_history` branch of your code. I'd suggest also putting that into the `backup_full` branch. If nothing else, you'll get an error message telling you what the problem is. Additionally, what does `msdb.dbo.backuphistory` and related tables say? Is it possible that the backup is happening successfully in a way that you don't expect?

Comment: @BenThul I once provide error handling but since it is a success there's no error message. The thing is, once I clear php artisan cache the file appear but just one of them, the last one. When I clear the cache once again, it still disappeared. When I check in msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily and msdb.dbo.backupset it isn't recorded even the succesful one.

Comment: "isn't recorded, even the successful one". That is an extraordinary claim. That is, maybe the server you think you're taking the backup on is not the one you're looking at?

Comment: @BenThul no, it's the right server, local server. when I run the stored procedure directly from .bat file, it's on the record. But, when access the stored procedure from php function it's not on the record. The file, I see it appear and disappear in the destination folder.

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56433567/php-pdofetch-assoc-doesnt-detect-select-after-backup-in-stored-procedure/56438860#56438860).